# How to send predefined email template in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am now developing one web application in vb.net. In that application I have one requirement. i.e. I have to send predefined email template to registered users. In that template I have to add some text messages like greeting messages or welcome messages. How to send predefined email templates in vb.net?

Comment: You can keep this predefined message text in a string and append only username(which is variable) at the time of sending email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the email html in sql or in a text file. make sure to leave placeholders for variables like

```
<span id="user">{user}</span>
```

and then replace "{user}" with the database value in a loop.